# Mathematical blogs on "non-standard" platforms (Telegram, Twitter, Dzen , ... )

Tags: soft-question

There are many well-known excellent blogs like the ones by T. Tao, G. Kalai, J. Baez, etc. Many of them use the WordPress engine.

I have been surprised to find that there are some excellent blogs on some unconventional platforms like [Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software)) (created in particular by mathematician [Nikolai Durov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Durov)) or Twitter. Telegram blogs ("channels") seem to be "invisible" outside Telegram.

**Question:** what are some not so well-known, but noteworthy math blogs  on some "non-standard" platforms, especially invisible from the outside?

Let me give some examples. Some of the following blogs by MathOverflow participants:

Twitter:

- [@littmath](https://twitter.com/littmath)  (in English) by [Daniel Litt](https://mathoverflow.net/users/6950/daniel-litt)

Telegram:

- [Graphs and Machine Learning](https://t.me/graphML) (in English)   by Sergei Ivanov
- [Математические байки](https://t.me/mathtabletalks) (in Russian) by [Victor Kleptsyn](https://mathoverflow.net/users/31371/victor-kleptsyn)
- [tropical saint petersburg](https://t.me/tropicalgeometry) (in Russian) by [Nikita Kalinin](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4298/nikita-kalinin)
- [fpmath](https://t.me/fedyap)  ( English/Russian ) by [Fedor Petrov](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4312/fedor-petrov)
- [Математическая свалка Сепы](https://t.me/math_dump_of_sepa) (in Russian) by Sergei O. Ivanov

Comment: I know we extend a lot of flexibility to higher-reputation users, and for a reason, but this is not a research-level mathematics question.

Comment: @LSpice thank you for your comment, I might admit that "softness" of that question might be too much for MO , however it is strange for me to hear that research blogs by research people is not "research level".

Comment: I think questions that *mention* research math are not the same as research-level mathematics questions; but it is rightly not up to me to decide!  As I say, users like you get to high reputation because of your valued and valuable contributions, so, if you feel that this is appropriate and the community receives it well, then that's what matters.

Comment: Thanks for advertisement, but my channel is not in Russian. Also I am not sure whether this question is ok or not.

Comment: @FedorPetrov corrected. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Check out https://mathstodon.xyz/explore. Though I don't read it myself, I believe a bunch of mathematicians that were on Google+ went there, after it shut down.

Comment: An extensive list of mathematical blogs is at [MathBlogging.org](https://mathblogging.org) It currently lists 149 blogs on Twitter.

Comment: https://t.me/cme_channel "Непрерывное математическое образование" - math and math education, partly aggregation other math telegram channels

Comment: https://t.me/obznam "Общий знаменатель" Разговоры о математике

Comment: https://t.me/MathematicsTips Математические хитрости

Comment: Link to collection to telegram chats? on math - https://github.com/goq/telegram-list#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: https://t.me/diagrams_every_day  совершенно замечательный молодой канал - интереснейшие визуализации и объяснения простыми словами современных концепций в физике и математике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

44 Telegram math channels are [here](https://t.me/math_channels) (5 in English).

Comment: On a cursory look, it doesn't seem to me that any of these would count as "blogs". Would you mind expanding a bit what these channels exactly are?

Comment: @Wojowu Imho it is nice answer, collecting all math blogs on telegram.  "Channel" just the name of personal blog on telegram platform. In contrast to chats - where many people can write.

Comment: PS the downvotes seems to me incorrect.

Comment: It was a mistake for the OP to accept this answer: first, if I follow the link I am presented with some text in Russian, which not that many people speak; second, in order to read those "channels" or whatever they are I need to install Telegram, whereas a blog can be read simply with the aid of a browser. This means that the information presented at that link is doubly inaccessible: part of it is in a language that few people speak, and it needs specialized software to be installed.

Comment: @AlexM. You are twice incorrect: 1) NO need to install telegram - web browser is enough - just click the link and choose "preview channel" (written in English by the way)  and you can view ANY telegram channel in that manner  2) Russian language for some of the channels seems not be an obstacle for accepting the answer - first google.translate builtin in browsers give you good translation from any language, second there is big Russian community on MO for whom answer is helpful, and the third there was no restriction in my question to English language.